Pytest tests with yield
I'm trying to write a PyTest suite in which:

I have multiple tests (test_logic_1, test_logic_2, test_logic_3), each running a 'before' logic one after the other.
After these tests, there is an upgrade test (test_upgrade) that runs on the test machine.
Once the upgrade is complete, all the 'after' logic is run in each of the initial tests.

Here’s a simplified version of my code:
def test_logic_1():
    # before logic
    yield
    # after logic

def test_logic_2():
    # before logic
    yield
    # after logic

def test_logic_3():
    # before logic
    yield
    # after logic

def test_upgrade():
    # upgrade test machine

How can I structure my PyTest suite to achieve this flow?

Hi. Ok. So what is the issue? There is no question in your post.

Don't use tests to create the setup and teardown logic, that's what fixtures are for.
There are several option to trigger those fixtures, use autouse=True
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup_logic_1():
    print("before logic 1")
    yield
    print("after logic 1")


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup_logic_2():
    print("before logic 2")
    yield
    print("after logic 2")


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup_logic_3():
    print("before logic 3")
    yield
    print("after logic 3")


def test_upgrade():
    print("test_upgrade")

or call them from the test if the fixture provide any data for the test
@pytest.fixture
def setup_logic_1():
    print("before logic 1")
    yield
    print("after logic 1")


@pytest.fixture
def setup_logic_2():
    print("before logic 2")
    yield
    print("after logic 2")


@pytest.fixture
def setup_logic_3():
    print("before logic 3")
    yield
    print("after logic 3")


def test_upgrade(setup_logic_1, setup_logic_2, setup_logic_3):
    print("test_upgrade")

Output
before logic 1
before logic 2
before logic 3
test_upgrade
after logic 3
after logic 2
after logic 1

